# Keeping qbittorrent when moving from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: qbittorrent

I foolishly initially installed 32 bit xubuntu on a new drive. I am going upgrade to 64 bit ubuntu. What files, etc. do I keep to have qbittorrent maintain files it is currently seeding.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to backup the following folders, as well as the downloaded data:

```
~/.config/qBittorrent/
~/.local/share/data/qBittorrent/
```

[info source](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#Where_does_qBittorrent_save_its_settings)